# Plesk send Email TLS not available

Tags: email, ssl, plesk

Mail from Plesk.

But i recieve this answer

```
Out: 220 **DOMAIN** ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
In:  EHLO [10.33.205.183]
Out: 250-**DOMAIN**
Out: 250-PIPELINING
Out: 250-SIZE 31457280
Out: 250-ETRN
Out: 250-STARTTLS
Out: 250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Out: 250-8BITMIME
Out: 250 DSN
In:  STARTTLS
Out: 454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
In:  ???
Out: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
In:  ?????(?'??????
Out: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
In:  ????
Out: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Out: 421 4.4.2 **DOMAIN** Error: timeout exceeded

Session aborted, reason: timeout

For other details, see the local mail logfile
```

Here is my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/tls/httpsd.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ***DOMAIN***
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.startdedicated.de, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 **IP**/32
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
non_smtpd_milters = 
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 31457280
```

I should say, that i not be an expert on linux and mailing!

The config file is located: /etc/postfix/main.cf
The cert /etc/postfix/tls/httpsd.pem is the servers default cert.

Thank you!

Comment: Check mail log at `/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/maillog`

Answer (score 0):

TL;TR: both bad client and bad server.

The mail server you use is configured wrong in that it believes it can to TLS (as seen in EHLO containing STARTTLS) but then fails to actually use TLS (error when client tries to use TLS). Additionally the client simply ignores the error message to the STARTTLS command and continues with the TLS handshake. This causes error messages from the server which expects proper SMTP commands but instead gets what looks like garbage (the TLS ClientHello).

Comment: Do you think, that i can send u my config, that you get a look at this? That would be friendly!

Comment: @FloBiber: no private Q+A. Please share the information inside your question so that everybody can help or can profit from the answer.